# The global alpha seemingly loses precision in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, alpha

I am trying to add a fade effect in JavaFX and am trying to do so using an AnimationTimer and by editing the Global Alpha. So far I have the following:

```
var fader = new AnimationTimer() {

      @Override
      public void handle(long now) {

        var gc = getGraphicsContext2D();

        if (gc.getGlobalAlpha() - 0.05 <= 0) {
          gc.setGlobalAlpha(1.0);
          paintEmpty();
          stop();
        } else {
          gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

          gc.setGlobalAlpha(gc.getGlobalAlpha() - 0.01);
         
          gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
          gc.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
          System.out.println(gc.getGlobalAlpha());
        }

      }
    };
    fader.start();
```

This works but causes a blue spike at the end and the output of the print statements, although it initially follows the expected trend (ie. 0.99,0.98,0.97,0.96) the value suddenly changes down to say 0.9299999999999999. I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: [_What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic_](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/800-7895/800-7895.pdf).

Comment: Could you do this with a FadeTransition on the canvas instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Speed over accuracy

Floating-point technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution.

Simplified version of your code.

```
double d = 1.0d ;
while ( d > 0.89d ) {
    d = d - 0.01 ;
    System.out.println( d ) ;
}
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/aPr9VF).

```
0.99
0.98
0.97
0.96
0.95
0.94
0.9299999999999999
0.9199999999999999
0.9099999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.8899999999999999
```

## Accuracy over speed

If you prefer accuracy over speed, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

Notice how we pass strings to the constructor rather than `float`/`double` primitives.

```java
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal( "1.0" );
BigDecimal limit = new BigDecimal( "0.89" );
BigDecimal decrement = new BigDecimal( "0.01" );

while ( d.compareTo( limit ) > 0 )
{
    d = d.subtract( decrement );
    System.out.println( d );
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/sVA23x).

```
0.99
0.98
0.97
0.96
0.95
0.94
0.93
0.92
0.91
0.90
0.89
```